# Another exception was thrown: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/about", null) in the _WidgetsAppState

Tags: flutter, dart

```
      case 1:
              //chagne to home page
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, ('/about'));
              break;
      case 2:
              // change to profile page
              print('Trying to access /profile');
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Profile()),
              );
              break;
```

I checked for typos in the app routes, The about page dossen't work but the profile page does .
This problem started after modifying the home page which chooses weather to display the login or the app page after checking the login state of user

Main.dart

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: AuthService().userstream, 
        builder:(context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          {
            print("waiting");
            return const Text('Waiting');
            }else if(snapshot.hasError ){
              print("error");
              return const Text('Error');
            }else if(snapshot.hasData){
              print("data");
              return const Topics();
            }else{
              print("login");
              return const Login();
            }
            });
  }
```